# stack corruption checking method

Tags: stack, overflow

1) how to initialize the stack with some unique pattern? so i can check it on the exit? sample program plz
2) how to add values in prolog and check it in epilog ? sample program plz

- valgrind and electric fence doesnt work with my multithreaded app it is too bulky i want some simple trick like
- add const value in prolog
- check it back in epilog

thanks,
Vj

Comment: initilize the stack in what!? where!? be more specific please!

Comment: Easy: Use a modern compiler that does it for you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Epilog and Prolog are two different languages, or are you talking about a different language altogether?

Answer (score 0):

In your first question I think you are talking about preventing the execution stack from being overran. There are different technique to archive this, but I think the one closest to "some unique pattern" is the canary.
**Theory:**
The canary is a (random) check value that is placed just below the functions return address. Before returning from the function, the system checks if the canary has the same value as before. If not, the stack has been overran, since the memory is written from lower to higher addresses, and you can't trust the return address.
**How it's done:**

1. When the return address are placed
   on the stack, the canary is placed
   there as well.
2. When the function exits, the canary is checked. If the canary has been altered, terminate the program (or whatever you find appropriate).

More information about canary values can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canary_value).
This (or some other stack overrun prevention technique) are generally implemented in modern compilers.

I have no idea about your second question.